# Tipsi stripe not working with android react native

Tags: stripe-payments, react-native

I am working in RN 0.57.1 and because of stripe latest updates i need to upgrade my stripe package. App is working fine with iOS build but the android build failed regular, I am totally confused here how to fix this.

Here is my build.gradle code:

```
ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 19
      compileSdkVersion = 28
      targetSdkVersion = 27
      supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
      googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
```

Here is Error:

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource linking failed
  >    /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/847adf56c6204cd8db834c9987a748e4/stripe-3ds2-android-1.2.2/res/values/values.xml:84:5-86:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/boxBackgroundColor (aka com.mybeautysquad.customer:attr/boxBackgroundColor)' not found.

Please let me know if anyone can help me into this...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on the latest version of RN using a very similar set up as you. 
https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/504#issuecomment-583566852